# Subsection Table of Contents in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to create a outline like this in my slide deck, but between every subsection of my talk. (Instead of between sections). Any ideas of how I accomplish this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: yes, my question is a duplicated of your linked question!

Comment: Good :). Then we can close your question.